# updating text box after ajax file upload

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I am using [this](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx) Ajax file upload in my project and it's working fine, my only problem is how can I save the path of the photo the I just uploaded? 
basically I tried to copy the path to a TextBox control after a successful upload and surround that text box with an updatepanel and update that panel manually after calling the Ajax's SaveAs method, but it doesn't seem to work.

this is the code for the the uploadedComplete event:

```
protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete (object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        if (AsyncFileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            var relativeFolder = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + DateTime.Now.Month +
                             Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
            relativeFolder = relativeFolder.Replace('\\', '/');
            var folder = Utils.RelativeWebRoot + "PostPhotos/" + relativeFolder;
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);

            AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(folder + fileName));

            txtPostPhoto.Text = folder + fileName;
            PostImage.ImageUrl = txtPostPhoto.Text;

            PostPhotoUpdatePanel.Update();
        }
    }
```

txtPostPhoto is my text box.

PostImage is where I am trying to display the image preview.

is there another way of doing this?

Comment: try to save photopath in a ViewState

Comment: and how can I pass the view state to the client side? I want it to appear in the text box and in the image web control.

Comment: in client side you can get it by usin its Key

Comment: can you give me an example? I have never done something like that before.

Comment: ok wait. I will post it as a answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to save photopath in a ViewState

```
protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete (object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
     ViewState["path"] = "your path"
     Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("vpath", ViewState("path"))
}
```

In client side place a script tag,

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var vCode = document.getElementById("vpath");
</script>
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. in debug mode I see that the param value is still null.

Answer (score 1):

See your example in the [link](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx) carefully.

Use the following property of the AJAX control:

```
OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete"
```

It is a javascript function fired on the server side when the file successfully uploaded. You can set the textbox value in this function.

Example:

```
function uploadComplete(sender, args) {
    var txt= document.getElementById("ctl00_SampleContent_clientSide");//Your textbox id
    txt.value=args.get_fileName();
}
```

Comment: I want to save the entire picture path so I will be able to use it for previewing the picture and saving it to my DB. the problem is that I build the path on the server side, is there a way to transfer it to the client side?

Answer (score 0):

You should save the path in a database, and instead of saving by name, you should rather save by creating a GUID and using the GUID as the name.

Why?

1. Consider a scenario where two images have the same name, one will be obviously overwritten, 
   using GUID will help in those cases.
2. Storing in the database can latter help you in identifying or deleting the image if you don't need it any more.

Comment: thanks, the image path is saved in the DB but only after the user save the form. that's the reason I use ajax, your GUID idea is great I will definitely try to implement it on my application.

Comment: You could use another database for the very purpose.